# Uncaught ReferenceError: WE is not defined in WebGL Earth

Tags: javascript, webgl, webgl2, webgl-earth

I'm implementing WebGL Earth on my local system i'm getting this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: WE is not defined
```

I have checked this link also

https://codepen.io/sketchpads/pen/WRVrQK?editors=1111

still getting the same error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: WE is not defined   at
> https://cdpn.io/cp/internal/boomboom/pen.js?key=pen.js-1cdbdb91-b3f9-3e06-0627-7cd650ea5199:3

http://examples.webglearth.com/#helloworld

[image]

> Code:

```html
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: white;
        font-family: "MyWebFont";
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      #earth_div {
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute !important;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.webglearth.com/v2/api.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var options = {
          sky: true,
          atmosphere: true,
          zooming: true,
        };
        var earth = new WE.map("earth_div", options);
        WE.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
          //tileSize: 256,
          //tms: true
        }).addTo(earth);

        // Start a simple rotation animation
        var before = null;
        requestAnimationFrame(function animate(now) {
          var c = earth.getPosition();
          var elapsed = before ? now - before : 0;
          before = now;
          earth.setCenter([c[0], c[1] + 0.1 * (elapsed / 30)]);
          requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        });

        var markerCustom = WE.marker(
          [50, -9],
          "../background_globe/img/logo-webglearth-white-100.png",
          100,
          24
        ).addTo(earth);

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
          var marker = WE.marker([
            position.coords.latitude,
            position.coords.longitude,
          ]).addTo(earth);
          marker
            .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br>My current location<br />", {
              maxWidth: 150,
              closeButton: true,
            })
            .openPopup();
        });
        // earth.setView([51.505, 0], 2.5);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="earth_div"></div>
  </body>
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: pls share your code here

Comment: I do not see same kind of error from codepen link.

Comment: @ZhefengJin: Added my code in the question above, Please check

Comment: checked but can not see the same error. starange

Comment: yes i have checked it on other systems also webgl is also supported but when i run https://github.com/webglearth/webglearth2-offline and working on local system it is working

Comment: You may want to focus on the first error first. `api.js` could not be parsed at all due to a syntax error.

Comment: @tevemadar but this error is on webgl side

Comment: The page contains `<script src="https://www.webglearth.com/v2/api.js"></script>`, and then the first thing in the console is *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' api.js:1*. `WE` stands for ***W***ebGL ***E***arth, and comes from that `api.js`. Except that it doesn't as there was something wrong about it when the screenshot was taken.

Comment: The code was wrapped into a snippet and appears to work in Chrome/Firefox/Edge.